# Paypal iOS SDK return me an error and crash my app

Tags: ios, swift, paypal

I implemented Paypal iOS SDK in my app and it works perfectly. Only for 1 account (1!) I can't login and as I write in title the SDK crash my app. In the logs I see the following error:

```
PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: stepup_required - Non è possibile completare l’accesso. Riprova più tardi o accedi a www.paypal.it per risolvere eventuali problema di sicurezza del tuo conto PayPal. (401) | PayPal Debug-ID: 6dcc0fceceb0d [live, PayPal iOS SDK 2.13.1] | Details: (
       {
       "error_description" = "Unable to authenticate the user, and a limited token is being returned. Stepping up the user with this Access Token via authentication flows is necessary. Authflow push notifications are disabled";
   }
).
```

I tried to search it into Paypal github but without success. Any ideas?

Comment: so you are using the Paypal SDK code as show in the github demo? and you are not able to login in the paypal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the last update of Paypal iOS SDK framework this problem disappear.

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this problem. Got solution by updating PayPal SDK framework.